# Discretize the nonlinear Hammerstein operator

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, discrete-optimization, integral-equations

I would like to know please how to discretize the following special instance of nonlinear Hammerstein operator (in matlab if it is possible):

$F : H^{1}[0,1] \rightarrow L^{2}[0,1],$

$ F(x)(s):=\int_{0}^s x(t)^{3}dt$

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Can you provide more details, like what is the interval you're working on, what is $n$, what exactly do you mean by discretization? Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: @ajr , i apologize for the missing information, i have edited the question. Actually i want to use this function to define a nonlinear inverse problem, and for the implementation part, i need to discretize this integral and get a nonlinear system in form of A(x) = b.